# NativeScript refuses to detect my avdmanager emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, nativescript, avd-manager

Trying to create a NativeScript app, but having started up my emulator, `tns device android --available-devices` won't detect it:
[image]
My Android SDK is installed at /usr/local/android/sdk, and I've made sure to delete every other installation of it that exists. `tns doctor` returns no errors, so I assume that this isn't the issue.
[image]
It's probably worth mentioning that I'm using Kubuntu, which I'm pretty sure is the reason the emulator crashes if I click one of the side menu buttons, but I think that's unrelated. The emulator definitely exists too:
[image]

If anyone has any ideas or needs anymore information, please don't hesitate to ask. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not have conflicting SDK installations? I've experienced conflicting SDKs when I install NativeScript - ensure that NativeScript is pointed to the same SDK that Android Studio is using.

Have you checked your bash profile?

Comment: Yep, bash profile points to the same android installation. I assume NativeScript uses whatever's in $ANDROID_HOME, right?

Comment: I'm on a mac, but i have the following set:

    # ANDROID ENVS
    export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk.  
    export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
    export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/$USER/.android/avd
    export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
    export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/gradle/bin

Comment: I think I've figured it out. Because I put my sdk in /usr/local/, I was using sudo to access it. Therefore, my emulator existed only for the root user. Running tns device with sudo fixed the issue and it was able to detect it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a mac, but i have the following set:

```
# ANDROID ENVS
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk.  
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/$USER/.android/avd
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/gradle/bin
```